# checked property of checkbox not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, angular

```
  <input
   type="checkbox"
   [(ngModel)]="loc.Selected"
   [checked]="loc.Selected"
   [value]="loc.Selected"
   class="checkbox col-xs-1"
   name="Countries"
   (change)="addPrimaryLocationItems()" />{{loc.LocationName}}
```

In the above code snippet the checkbox was not checked inspite of that the value was true and in some cases when the value is false still the checkbox is checked.

Did anyone know why i get this unstable behaviour of checked property in this.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `[checked]="loc.Selected"`. use only

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   [(ngModel)]="loc.Selected"
   [value]="loc.Selected"
   class="checkbox col-xs-1"
   name="Countries"
   (change)="addPrimaryLocationItems()" />{{loc.LocationName}}
```